# Using Pandas to visualize data from a custom Python array object

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I am trying to implement a python object that has an array interface and I am interested in seeing if I can use pandas to visualize data from my object. I am basically trying this example from the [10 minutes to pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html). The numpy version is

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4), index=dates, columns=list('ABCD'))
```

Now I want to do something like this

```
import pandas as pd
import <my_module> as np
a = <array object from my module of size (6,4) with python float values>
df = pd.DataFrame(a, index=dates, columns=list('ABCD'))
```

Sure enough, that gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File ".../Python-3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas-0.18.1-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/frame.py", line 303, in __init__
  raise PandasError('DataFrame constructor not properly called!')
```

Now, the array object I create works with the numpy.array routine

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import <my_module> as gnp
>>> a = <array object from my_module of size (6,4) with python float values>
>>> anp = np.array(a)
>>> print(anp)
array([[ 1.65596968, -2.39189608, -2.92223678, -1.0312887 ],
       [ 0.41918582,  2.35760521,  3.97045546,  1.06558325],
       [-0.29084453,  1.43759343,  2.94189788,  0.07185253],
       [-1.51164217,  0.9233231 ,  2.05859341,  2.62394528],
       [ 0.12106421, -1.03187945,  2.36255711,  0.86845971],
       [-1.39774121,  5.17955785, -1.05458446, -2.10051246]])
```

I looked at the code around the specific exception in .../pandas/core/frame.py. The code is in constructor of a DataFrame object

```
 def __init__(self, data=None, index=None, columns=None, dtype=None,
             copy=False):

     elif isinstance(data, (np.ndarray, Series, Index)):
          ....
     else:
         try:
             arr = np.array(data, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
         except (ValueError, TypeError) as e:
             exc = TypeError('DataFrame constructor called with '
                            'incompatible data and dtype: %s' % e)
             raise_with_traceback(exc)
         if arr.ndim == 0 and index is not None and columns is not None:
             ....
         else:
             raise PandasError('DataFrame constructor not properly called!')
```

So technically what I am trying should work, I would expect, that if it is possible to create an numpy array object using np.array, pandas should be able to handle that object similar to the way it handles the case when a numpy array is passed in. Instead, it looks like it tries to enforce the condition for the array being size 0. Is this a pandas bug or I am trying something that is not feasible?

I am sorry for the long post, but this is the only way I can convey the full problem. I will really appreciate any response that help me figure out what's going on.

**EDIT**

This is the change that I thought would be needed. With this it seems like I get what I want. Hoping someone from Pandas responds

```
    else:
        try:
            arr = np.array(data, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
        except (ValueError, TypeError) as e:
            exc = TypeError('DataFrame constructor called with '
                            'incompatible data and dtype: %s' % e)
            raise_with_traceback(exc)

        if isinstance(arr, (np.ndarray, Series, Index)):
            if data.dtype.names:
                data_columns = list(data.dtype.names)
                data = dict((k, data[k]) for k in data_columns)
            if columns is None:
                columns = data_columns
                mgr = self._init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
            elif getattr(data, 'name', None):
                mgr = self._init_dict({data.name: data}, index, columns,
                                      dtype=dtype)
            else:
                mgr = self._init_ndarray(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype,
                                         copy=copy)

        elif arr.ndim == 0 and index is not None and columns is not None:
            if isinstance(data, compat.string_types) and dtype is None:
                dtype = np.object_
            if dtype is None:
                dtype, data = _infer_dtype_from_scalar(data)

            values = np.empty((len(index), len(columns)), dtype=dtype)
            values.fill(data)
            mgr = self._init_ndarray(values, index, columns, dtype=dtype,
                                     copy=False)
        else:
            raise PandasError('DataFrame constructor not properly called!')
```